# Cycle and line graph

Tags: graph-theory

$G=(S,A)$ is a simple graph and $n=|S| \geq 3$ and his line graph L(G)

How to prove that :
We suppose that G is a cycle with n vertices where each vertex is of degree 2 then the line-graph of G is a cycle. And if G is a cycle, then it is isomorphic to it's line graph. What is the bijection ?

Comment: Consider a cycle with n vertices, it has n edges in its path. By these edges as
vertices in L(Cn), we form a cycle with n edges. This implies that, both Cn and L(Cn)
has same number of vertices and edges and also have the same degree sequence. 
I don't understand how to find the bijection.

Comment: I don't even know for a cycle with 4 vertices

Comment: I have already drawn G and its line graph as you told me. The line graph is also a cycle and the vertex v0 becomes v0v1 v1 becomes v1v2 ... 
But i don't find how to explicitly give isomorphism.